# Current value of two serial transistors

Tags: mosfet, current-measurement, nmos, pmos

How can I prove that the current value (Ids) of two serial transistors (nmos) with equivalent W/L values is equal to the current value of one transistor with W/2L (In linear region)? (Ids1 = Ids2 in the picture)

[image]

Comment: Hint: Schematic 1, its not 2 parallel transistors, they both are in series and hence same current flows in both the transistors.

Comment: @rsg1710 Thanks for your hint , it was my mistake. I editted my question.

Comment: Another hint: write down the equations of Ids for both schematic. You will get your answer as soon as you write them down. Also figure out which region they are operating and then write their Ids equation accordingly.

Comment: Think about the **physical** buildup 2 W/L MOS in series vs 1 W/2L MOS. The channel under the gate sets the conductivity between Drain and source. What does the channel look like in each case?

Comment: @baran.jl judging from schematic, I can tell you that all transistors are nmos.

Comment: @rsg1710 My exact problem is that i don't know how to measure the Ids in serial schema!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know how to write equations here, so let me follow the traditional way. In the second figure, the mosfet is in linear region. So we can write its current Ids1 as:
[image] Okay now in the first figure, currents through the series mosfets are same and its equal to Ids2. Both the mosfets are in linear region here. So we can find I1 and I2 separately and equate both to reach at a final expression for Ids2. The final expressions for Ids1 and Ids2 are found to be the same. Hence Ids1 = Ids2
[image]

Comment: Go [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for proper MathJax info if you want to know how to make equations. Or right click on an equation on this site and choose "show math as > tex commands". Do it on this equation right here: \$I_{DS2}=\frac{KW}{L}...\$. If you're too lazy, then this is what it looks like in my comment window. \\$I_{DS2}=\frac{KW}{L}...\\$

Comment: @MITURAJ Hello again. I have another question. Is Ids1 equal to Ids2 considering Body Effect?

Comment: In this question, threshold voltages of all mosfets are assumed to be the same. Body effect comes into play only if the body voltage of each mosfet, VBs is at some voltage other than 0. It can change their threshold voltages and hence currents. Anyway no info about that is given in the question. @baranji